# Sql query to pick up values on some rules

Tags: sql, rank

Im kind of stuck at a problem that looks simple. Can somebody please help me on this one?
The actual table has 25 columns.
But basically to form this question lets say it looks something like this:

```
SR  |  Type |  Des | Code
-------------------------
1   |   wo  |  abc | 100   
-------------------------
2   |   co  |  def | 100   
-------------------------
3   |   wo  |  ghi | 200  
-------------------------
4   |   co  |  jkl | 200    
-------------------------
5   |   co  |  mno | 200    
-------------------------
```

My query is supposed to group by "`Code`". "`Type`" should be taken from the first row and "`Des`" should be taken from the latest set.

I want my result set as following:

```
SR  |  Type |  Des | Code
-------------------------
1   |   wo  |  def | 100
-------------------------
3   |   wo  |  mno | 200
```

Can someone write this query for me please?

Comment: Post the query you are using now.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Using sqlServer..! I got it... My whole dapproach was wrong..Thnks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a go at your query. The Sub Query in the FROM clause gets the grouping by CODE and determines what the min and max values are for SR. Once we have this we join back into the main table on CODE and the minSR\maxSR values to get the corresponding Type and Des values. This makes the assumption that every CODE will always have a minSR and maxSR value. If this is not the case, change the INNER JOINs to Left JOINs.

Please Note TABLE = the name of your example table above. Also the value of SR in the result set is the minimum value of SR as in your example result set.

```
    Select cg.CODE, tmin.Type, tmax.Des, tmin.SR
    FROM (
          Select CODE, Min(SR) as MinSR, MAX(SR) as MaxSR
          FROM TABLE
          GROUP BY CODE
         ) cg
    INNER JOIN TABLE tmin ON cg.CODE = tmin.Code
                             AND cg.MinSR = tmin.SR

    INNER JOIN TABLE tmax ON cg.CODE = tmax.Code
                             AND cg.MaxSR = tmax.SR
```

Comment: It works.. :) I didnt know we could actually give somthing like "tmin" and "tmax"..
Cool aprroach... U all have such good appraoches to problem..

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started. I'm sure it could be improved with some strategic joins (to prevent having to name every column), but it works.

```
DECLARE @mytable TABLE ( 
    SR   INT IDENTITY(1, 1), 
    Type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    Des  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    Code INT 
) 

INSERT INTO @mytable (Type, Des, Code) VALUES ('wo', 'abc', 100);
INSERT INTO @mytable (Type, Des, Code) VALUES ('co', 'def', 100);
INSERT INTO @mytable (Type, Des, Code) VALUES ('wo', 'ghi', 200);
INSERT INTO @mytable (Type, Des, Code) VALUES ('co', 'jkl', 200);
INSERT INTO @mytable (Type, Des, Code) VALUES ('co', 'mno', 200);

SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT TOP 1 SR 
                 FROM   @mytable 
                 WHERE  Code = Summary.Code 
                 ORDER  BY SR ASC)  AS SR, 
                (SELECT TOP 1 Type 
                 FROM   @mytable 
                 WHERE  Code = Summary.Code 
                 ORDER  BY SR ASC)  AS Type, 
                (SELECT TOP 1 Des 
                 FROM   @mytable 
                 WHERE  Code = Summary.Code 
                 ORDER  BY SR DESC) AS Des, 
                Code 
FROM   @mytable Summary
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using ANSI window functions:

```
select sr, 
       first_type as type, 
       last_des as des,
       code
from (
   select sr,
          type, 
          des,
          code,
          first_value(type) over (partition by code order by sr rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as first_type,
          last_value(des) over (partition by code order by sr rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as last_des,
          row_number() over (partition by code order by sr ) as rn
   from data
) t
where rn = 1
order by sr
```

SQLFiddle example

- for Postgres: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f6117/1
- for Oracle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3019f/1

Comment: Wow...!! it works... Il write for my table in similar way...
Thankssss sooo muchhhh genius..! :)
U knw d query dat i wrote appears absolutely crap..Guess i need to work a lot more in sql... :(